# Trying to extract data from divs within divs in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Here is the html:

```
<div class="AcuityResearchTerminalWidget__padding__S4eul undefined">
   <div class="EventInfo__wrapper__Gkjqn" style="background-color: rgb(23, 32, 42); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
      <div class="EventInfo__title__JBkYo">Consumer Price Index (MoM </div>
      <div class="EventInfo__detailsWrapper__vBTGX" style="border-color: rgb(13, 24, 33);">
      <div class="EventInfo__affectedAssetsWrapper__gjMXZ">
         <div class="EventInfo__title__JBkYo">What Assets does this event affect?</div><div class="EventInfo__affectedAssets__UNDjB">
         <div role="button" class="EventInfo__affectedAsset__iQlBc" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(23, 32, 42);"><span>EURUSD</span></div>
         <div role="button" class="EventInfo__affectedAsset__iQlBc" style="background: rgb(23, 32, 42); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span>EURAUD</span></div>
         <div role="button" class="EventInfo__affectedAsset__iQlBc" style="background: rgb(23, 32, 42); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span>EURCAD</span></div>
         <div role="button" class="EventInfo__affectedAsset__iQlBc" style="background: rgb(23, 32, 42); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span>EURCHF</span></div>
         <div role="button" class="EventInfo__affectedAsset__iQlBc" style="background: rgb(23, 32, 42); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span>EURCZK</span></div>
```

There seems to be an error in my code/logic since I can't seem to extract the affected assets (ex: EURUSD).

Here is my code:

```
def extract_name_and_assets(html_content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    events = soup.find_all(class_='EventTile__wrapper__iAmCe')

    extracted_data = []

    for event in events:
        event_name = event.find(class_='EventTile__eventName__OBN72').text.strip()
        event_id = event['data-id']  # Extracting the data-id attribute
        extracted_data.append({'name': event_name, 'id': event_id})
        
        widget = event.find(class_="AcuityResearchTerminalWidget__padding__S4eul undefined")
        if widget:
            wrapper = widget.find(class_="EventInfo__affectedAssestsWrapper__gjMXZ")
            if wrapper:
                assets_wrapper = wrapper.find(class_="EventInfo__affectedAssets__UNDjB")
                if assets_wrapper:
                    expand_button_div = assets_wrapper.find('div', class_='EventInfo__expandButton__cDK9n')
                    if expand_button_div:
                        expand_button_div.div.next_sibling.string = "View All Assets"
                    assets = [asset.span.text.strip() for asset in assets_wrapper.find_all(class_="EventInfo__affectedAsset__iQlBc")]
                else:
                    assets = []
                extracted_data.append({'name': event_name, 'id': event_id, 'assets': assets})

    return extracted_data
```

Also per event, there are multiple assets but my code can't seem to extract any of the assets. Additionally, once I add the lines starting at `widget = event.find...`, the output csv would be empty (but before that, the event_name and event_id would work properly).

I tried accessing the assets directly through the code below but it still wouldn't work.

```
for event in events:
        event_name = event.find(class_='EventTile__eventName__OBN72').text.strip()
        event_id = event['data-id']  # Extracting the data-id attribute
        assets_wrapper = event.find(class_="EventInfo__affectedAssets__UNDjB")
        if assets_wrapper:
            assets = [asset.span.text.strip() for asset in assets_wrapper.find_all(class_="EventInfo__affectedAsset__iQlBc")]
        else:
            assets = []
        extracted_data.append({'name': event_name, 'id': event_id, 'assets': assets})

    return extracted_data
```

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Edit your question and add the code/HTML as text, properly formatted.

Comment: Does the page take a while to load? That may be why your data is empty. I would suggest you add some print statements in the different `if` tiers to make sure you are getting what you think you are before you get too deep. Also, you are using a lot of `.find(class=...)` and stacking them. You could instead use `.select()` and use a CSS selector that is a combination of most/all of those classes, e.g. `event.select(".AcuityResearchTerminalWidget__padding__S4eul .EventInfo__affectedAssestsWrapper__gjMXZ .EventInfo__affectedAssets__UNDjB")` and so on, where `.` indicates a class.

Comment: If you could post a link to the page, we could provide a lot more info.

Comment: Here is a link to the page: https://www.adss.com/en/analysis/economic-calendar/

Comment: There's no instances of "EURUSD" on that page. Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.